# Symfony cron job, strange error

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I have this symfony command that runs well locally and on the server. 
Locally, it works if I call it or if it goes through cron.

On the server side, it works if I call it on the shell window, but the moment cron calls it, it doesn't wanna work and throws me this strange error.

the command is `php ~/mg/app/console global:insert 1 -vv --env=prod`

And the error is

```
ContextErrorException in ArgvInput.php line 287: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

in ArgvInput.php line 287
at ErrorHandler->handleError('2', 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()', 'vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php', '287', array('values' => array('--ansi'))) in ArgvInput.php line 287
at ArgvInput->hasParameterOption(array('--ansi')) in Application.php line 823
at Application->configureIO(object(ArgvInput), object(ConsoleOutput)) in Application.php line 123
at Application->run(object(ArgvInput)) in console line 26
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated, first time I ever see this error message.

Command code

```
class GlobalInsertCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('global:insert')
        ->addArgument('env', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, '1 | 0',0);
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {

    $rootDir = $this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getRootDir();

    foreach (MyRepos::$SOURCES as $source):
        if($input->getArgument("env") == 1):
            $source .= " --env=prod";
        endif;
        MyRepos::runProcess("php $rootDir/console immobilier:insert $source -vv");
    endforeach;
}
```

}

The actual insertCommand

```
class InsertCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {


protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('immobilier:insert')
        ->setDescription('Take RawData and and insert into database')
        ->addArgument('source', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'all')
    ;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $this->pc = $this->getContainer()->get('Momoa.immobilier_cron.controller');
    try {
        $this->pc->setChoice($input->getArgument("source"));
        $this->pc->addAction();
    } catch(Exception $e){
          $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

And the Run Process method

```
    static function runProcess($command){
    $ps = new Process($command);
    $ps->enableOutput();
    $ps->setTimeout(null);
    $ps->run(function($type, $buffer) {
        echo "OUT > " . $buffer;
    });
}
```

Comment: show us the code, its the foreach which we cant see

Comment: Its not my code, its symfony code, you want to see my actual command code ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Show us the whole command file.

Comment: i don't care whose code it is, code got error, how can any one help without seeing it

Comment: I added the code. Sorry.

Comment: How does the command in your `cron` file look like?

Answer (score 8):

So I found the problem, The error is not related to the actual logic of the command file but the php.ini options.

First you need to be sure that this option is set to on `register_argc_argv=on` in your php.ini file.

If you can't change your php.ini file, declare the command as such:

`php-cli -d register_argc_argv=On /path/to/your/command`